# "flashbuilder" and "flash-builder" -- Aren't they the same thing? Can they please be merged?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, retag-request, synonym-request

[flash-builder](/questions/tagged/flash-builder) should remain the parent tag (1986 posts).

[flashbuilder](/questions/tagged/flashbuilder) should be a synonym merged into it (290 posts).

Comment: Additional justification - The official title of the application in question is "Adobe **Flash Builder**" (note the space)

Comment: This synonym request should be done!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, please fix.

For example, when I enter [soapclient](/questions/tagged/soapclient) I get an error telling me I should use [soap-client](/questions/tagged/soap-client). This should be at least the same with those two in my eyes.

Comment: Why are you bumping this with a completely different tag and a different issue?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: That's just an example I experienced which I thing should work analogue for the tags in question here. Was that not clear?

Answer (score 1):

They should obviously be merged. However, if you look at the tag wiki excerpts something else springs up:

[flashbuilder](/questions/tagged/flashbuilder)

> FlashBuilder is the Flex 4.0 replacement IDE for Adobe's FlexBuilder

[flash-builder](/questions/tagged/flash-builder)

> Adobe's official IDE for the Flex SDK.

This implies that [flashbuilder4](/questions/tagged/flashbuilder4) should also be included, the excerpt reads:

> FlashBuilder 4 stands for the version 4 of Adobe Flash Builder - an
>   IDE based on Eclipse used for building Flex/Flash applications.